# Apache Spark is taking longer than what the UI shows

Tags: pyspark

I am running a series of steps in PySpark. It is taking about 56 minutes to complete. But when I go to the UI, I can see the breakdown only for 9-12 mins in one stage and all other stages are in milliseconds. Is there any way that I can reduce the wait time and also the run time to those 9-12 mins?

Highly appreciate for your time. Thanks.

Comment: Spark UI would only show you the time by spark jobs and not by any other processing happening in python. You need to look at which part in your python code is taking most time which is not a spark job.

Comment: Theres no Python portion in the code as such. We just have a connection with Hive.